# Positioning a square in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below rectangle in my `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    theme_void() +
    geom_text(aes(0,0,label='Above is a square')) +
    xlab(NULL) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 3, ymin = 10, ymax = 15),  fill = "blue")
```

[image]

I actually want to draw a **square** with smaller size, not a rectangle. I also want to place this square in the middle of the window and place the text just under that.

Is there any way to perform this?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option using `coord_equal` which makes the scales equal and you can define the origin with 0, which makes it maybe easier to adjust the positions of text like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, 
                xmax = 1, 
                ymin = 0, 
                ymax = 1,
            ), fill = "blue") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(0.5,-0.1,label='Above is a square'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How can I make the square smaller? I tried with `geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0,  xmax = .1,  ymin = 0,  ymax = .1), fill = "blue")` but it is no longer positioned at center

Comment: Hi @BrianSmith, You should slight change the position of `geom_text` too, for example 0.05 and -0.01. If you check the coordinates when plotting without `theme_void`, you can see that the square is smaller, but it zooms back so it looks not smaller at first point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Use grid instead of ggplot2 (which internally uses grid):

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.rect(width = unit(2, "inches"),
          height = unit(2, "inches"),
          gp = gpar(fill = "blue", col = "blue"))
grid.text("Above is a square", 
          y = unit(0.2, "npc"))
```

[image: resulting plot showing a blue square in the middle and text below it]

This mixes absolute and relative units and might need adjustments depending on the dimensions of the graphics device.

Answer (score 0):

### Equal distance

You need to set equal distance in `geom_rect`. Currently your x-axis is of 2 units while y-axis is of 5. Also include `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)` to force same scale of x- and y-axis.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(12.5,9.5,label='Above is a square')) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 10, xmax = 15, ymin = 10, ymax = 15),  fill = "blue") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Different distance

If your coordinate is fixed and cannot be changed, then use `coord_fixed(ratio = 0.4)` to force it into a square.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(2,9.5,label='Above is a square')) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 3, ymin = 10, ymax = 15),  fill = "blue") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Smaller square

You can play with the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters to generate smaller square.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(2,9.5,label='Above is a square')) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 3, ymin = 10, ymax = 15),  fill = "blue") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.4, xlim = c(-5, 8), ylim = c(4, 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Remember to also change the x and y position of `geom_text` to have the text right under the square.